JFROG CLI download without overwrite
Default setting is not downloading a file with the same name. I want to download two files with the same filename from JFROG, but they are different (from different folders of JFROG).
jf rt dl path --retries=3
There should be an argument like for retries. I cannot find any commands on their homepage like that for no-overwrite. Is there any command for that? Or something like "ignore-existing"?
Searching on https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory

What do you want it to do when you ask to download two files with the same name? Store the second file with a different name? Store the two files in different directories? Make the second file overwrite the first?
